# How can I self-host Ubuntu One?

Tags: server, ubuntu-one, open-source, hosting

The Ubuntu One service is [closing and being open sourced](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/):

> Additionally, we continue to believe in the Ubuntu One file services,
>   the quality of the code, and the user experience, so will release the
>   code as open source software to give others an opportunity to build on
>   this code to create an open source file syncing platform.

How can I self-host the server and set up my Ubuntu One clients to use this server?

I looked at the Launchpad [project site](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone), but it seems that all the server-side code is still hidden.

Comment: I think it's a little early for this question :)

Comment: I don't think it will be open source as long as it is available as a service. It could potentially let hackers to find security holes.

Comment: Well, there's less than three months before our files on U1 get deleted. In this time, someone might develop an easy method to install a personal U1 server. If we get the source soon...

Comment: No, it's a little less than four months. We're at the beginning of April and files will be deleted in the end of July.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-ubuntu-one-server-side-application-proprietary

Answer (score 3):

You cannot self-host the server currently. It *will* be released as open source, meaning, some time in the future. There is still some work to do to make it possible to run it on arbitrary systems. When that happens, it should simply be a matter of using JuJu to deploy the service, or pulling it from the bzr branch and running it yourself.

Until then you will have to just wait, or write your own server based on the protocol, which is already open source.

Comment: Is there a timeline for that? As Ubuntu is cancelling the service it would be nice to have the possibility to a smooth transition to a self hosted service.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15294/why-is-the-ubuntu-one-server-side-application-proprietary